# Latest docker image does not point to really latest image version from private local registry

Tags: docker

I've created private local Docker registry using manual https://hackernoon.com/create-a-private-local-docker-registry-5c79ce912620 and pushed two versions of custom image to it. Then I deleted cached images and tried to pull image from local registry. Problem is that when I pull latest version it pulls version 0.1 instead of 0.2.

Here is `docker images` output:

```
REPOSITORY                                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
192.168.3.51:5000/ubuntu-avigdor-build-image   0.2                 2a11312a4409        12 minutes ago      1.2GB
192.168.3.51:5000/ubuntu-avigdor-build-image   0.1                 6c7519e8b4c9        6 days ago          990MB
192.168.3.51:5000/ubuntu-avigdor-build-image   latest              6c7519e8b4c9        6 days ago          990MB
```

As you can see, image with tag latest has image ID equal to image with tag 0.1. It is not what I want.

How could I make Docker pull image 0.2 version when I ask for latest? Have I missed something when I pushed and tagged images?

Comment: What command did you use to pull

Comment: @sudo, I use `sudo docker pull 192.168.3.51:5000/ubuntu-avigdor-build-image` and get image ID 6c7519e8b4c9, then same command but with tag 0.1 and get same 6c7519e8b4c9 again, then same sommand but with tag 0.2 and get 2a11312a4409

Comment: You can use the latest tag so docker will pull from the latest version i.e 0.2, 0.3.

Comment: @sudo, I tried `sudo docker pull 192.168.3.51:5000/ubuntu-avigdor-build-image:latest`, but still get 6c7519e8b4c9, same as for 0.1 version

Comment: Okay I would go against my previous suggestion of using the latest tag. Instead just use version tags. `docker pull 192.168.3.51:5000/ubuntu-avigdor-build-image:0.2`.